# Umbraco ezsearch - Not searching child conent nodes

Tags: search, umbraco, umbraco7

We're trying to integrate ezsearch into an Umbraco project.  So far we have installed the package and added the ezsearch onto our page.  We're not receiving search results from child nodes?  We've had no luck with Google searches. Any suggestions? We are very new to Umbraco.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that you have republished all the child nodes.

http://yourawesomedomain.com/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx

Also rebuild the index. So, in back office, go to Developer, then go to the Examine Management Tab, then choose the indexer you are using (probably the external indexer), Go to index info and tools, and click "Rebuild Index". You can also test your searches there: Examine Mgt >> Searchers >> External Searcher >> Search Tools.

Also make sure that you are configuring EzSearch to use & display all the relevant content properties/fields.

e.g.

```
        <umbraco:Macro 
            indexType="CONTENT" 
            pageSize="10" 
            previewFields="pageTitle, description, tagLine, topCopy, interiorCopy, mainCopy" 
            previewLength="250" 
            rootContentNodeId="-1"
            searchFields="pageTitle, description, tagLine, topCopy, interiorCopy, mainCopy" 
            searchFormLocation="BOTH" 
            Alias="ezSearch" 
            runat="server">
        </umbraco:Macro>
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks very much for getting back on this.  We gave up on ezsearch and went for Google CSE instead.  I had forgotten about this question :) I believe it wasn't working because the content we were searching was created from an Umbraco 3rd party plugin called SirTrevor - a plugin where the admin can drag images and add text content.